# Blur event ignoring the click event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the js code:

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#test1 ,#test2").blur(function() {
                alert("Blur of text box");
            });

            $("#buttonClick").click(function() {
                alert("Button clicked");
            });
        });
```

HTML code:

```
    <input type="text" name="test1" id="test1">
    <input type="text" name="test2" id="test2">
    <input type="button" value="Click" id="buttonClick">
```

Here the blur event & click event working fine separately but when the not in conjunction

what I mean is ex: if I write something in text box and click on button then
blur event gets called but the click not triggers

Any idea why this is happening, and what could be the solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because of the `alert()` it sets your application on hold. Use `console.log()`

Comment: VDesign is absolutely correct.

Comment: Why -1, kindly put a comment, I understand the @VDesign 's answer is right, but question is valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alert()` pauses the execution of the rest of your script until the alert pop-up is closed. Use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: This is already answered in the comment on question, still thank you for you reply!

Comment: @sandip I know, that's why I made it a community wiki answer - it's now more visible to people who visit the question in the future, and I don't get any reputation from it (since VDesign is the one who actually answered it).